# Handle Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am Aggregating the data  on 'INTERIM_AUTO' table  on the basis of  Unit ID,  Line ID, CURR_DATE i.e.

```
SELECT INTERIM_AUTO_ID,
       UNIT_ID,
       PROD_LINE_ID,
       CURR_DATE,
       BAL_AMOUNT,
       V_SOURCE_CODE,
       CURR_ID,
       CREATED_BY,
       UPDATED_DATETIME
  FROM INTERIM_AUTO
 WHERE CURR_DATE = to_date(V_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
 GROUP BY UNIT_ID,
          PROD_LINE_ID,
          CURR_DATE
```

And then if we get multiple entries for the above combination then  I have to do the summation of  BAL_Amount and consider the single entry for the above combination with this calculated  Amount. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Your SQL statement above will never run. It will return `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` because it contains columns in the `SELECT` clause that aren't in the `GROUP BY` clause. You can't do a partial grouping like this - your query can either aggregate by adding the missing fields to the `GROUP BY` or not aggregate by removing the `GROUP BY` completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to calculate the sum of the *BAL_AMOUNT* column. You can do this with the `SUM` function.

If you use `SUM` on your *BAL_AMOUNT* column, you will have to add all your other columns into the `GROUP BY`:

```
   SELECT INTERIM_AUTO_ID,
          UNIT_ID,
          PROD_LINE_ID,
          CURR_DATE,
          SUM(BAL_AMOUNT) as SUM_BAL_AMOUNT,
          V_SOURCE_CODE,
          CURR_ID,
          CREATED_BY,
          UPDATED_DATETIME
     FROM INTERIM_AUTO
    WHERE CURR_DATE = to_date(V_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
 GROUP BY UNIT_ID,
          PROD_LINE_ID,
          CURR_DATE,
          INTERIM_AUTO_ID,
          UNIT_ID,
          PROD_LINE_ID,
          V_SOURCE_CODE,
          CURR_ID,
          CREATED_BY,
          UPDATED_DATETIME;
```

Or remove the columns you don't need:

```
   SELECT UNIT_ID,
          PROD_LINE_ID,
          CURR_DATE,
          SUM(BAL_AMOUNT) as SUM_BAL_AMOUNT
     FROM INTERIM_AUTO
    WHERE CURR_DATE = to_date(V_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
 GROUP BY UNIT_ID,
          PROD_LINE_ID,
          CURR_DATE;
```

Comment: How do I consider the single entry for the above combination with this calculated Amount?

Comment: @ronan What do you mean? Can you update your question with some sample input data and the sample output format that you desire?